# Loop among various dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have several several dataframes(df1, df2, ..., df1000), all of them are in a nested list format and have exactly the same structure. Accessing the data for each dataframe is straight forward: just need to run the following line of code:

`df1_data <- df1$CompactData$DataSet$Series`

Since I have nearly a thousand dataframes, I have created a list with the names of these dfs to use them in a loop that would allow me to obtain the desired data as in the example above. However, I have not been able to find an answer to this and haven't been able to find a solution myself.

```
list_of_names <- list(df1, df2, …, df1000)

for (df in length(list_of_names)) {
  list_of_names[[df]] = list_of_names[[df]]$CompactData$DataSet$Series
}
```

Essentially, what I would like to achieve is to create new dataframes with the data that I really need.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a job for purrr::map(). Some good information about working on lists of data frames here: https://www.rebeccabarter.com/blog/2019-08-19_purrr/#simplest-usage-repeated-looping-with-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit messy, but you could use `eval(parse())`.

```
for(df in 1:length(list_of_names)) {
  list_of_names[[df]] = eval(parse(text = paste0(list_of_names[[df]], '$CompactData$DataSet$Series')))
}
```

Alternately, if you put your dataframes in a list, instead of just the names, you could use `lapply()` or `map()`.

```
# given list of data.frames, called df_list
df_sub <- lapply(df_list, function(x) x$CompactData$DataSet$Series)
```

`df_sub` will then contain your desired subset of all data.frames in `df_list`. Advantages to this approach are that it is easier to manage a list of data.frames, and the code is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your data correctly, I would first make a `list` of all your sequentially named `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, ...

```
start_list = mget(paste0("df", 1:1000))
```

Then something like your loop should work. I've changed things by (a) adding `1:` in `1:length())` loop set-up, and (b) iterating over the input, not the result:

```
result = list()
for (df in 1:length(list_of_names)) {
  result[[df]] = start_list[[df]]$CompactData$DataSet$Series
}
```

If you need more help than this, please share a reproducible sample of your data (which can be admittedly difficult with nested list structures. `str(df1)` would be a good start...)